# ReactTestUtils has been moved

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-test-renderer

I'm starting learning React and while I was doing some tests i noticed two warning messages:

> Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update references to remove this warning.
>
> Warning: Shallow renderer has been moved to react-test-renderer/shallow. Update references to remove this warning.

They don't prevent the tests from running nor from properly validating, but there is always this error.

By looking at the docs, I [found this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html#react-test-utils), even after I included those lines they recommend, the warning message is still showing up.

I'm trying a very simple test to start with, this is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import toJson from "enzyme-to-json";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { About } from "./About";

describe('Rendering test', () => {
    const component = shallow(<About />);
    const tree      = toJson(component);

    it('Should render the About component', () => {
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    })

    it('Should not contain an h2 element', () => {
        expect( component.contains('h2') ).toBe(false);
    })
})
```

What do I need to do in order to solve this warnings? I already updated all my packaged to the latest versions.

Comment: chech enzyme's package json/source code. they might still be using the old one

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think it's coming from using the `shallow` render function from enzyme, which has not been updated for v15.5 yet (there is a [pull request](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/pull/876) for it though).

You can try to use one of the other render function ([`render`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/render.md) or [`mount`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/mount.md)), but this will change the semantics of your test (and may or may not still produce the warning).

Your other option is to not use enzyme and use [`react-test-renderer/shallow` yourself](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-test-renderer#shallow-renderer), but the enzyme API is quite nice for testing components.

My advice is to wait for the version of enzyme and just live with the warning for now.

Comment: So, it may be worth waiting until they fix it, right? Since it's just a warning and nothing is breaking.

Comment: Totally.  The enzyme pull request shouldn't take long to go through.

Comment: I am getting this with React v15.1.0? How can I remove these warnings?

Comment: @VishalGulati, try [Pere Pages' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334942/reacttestutils-has-been-moved/43338870?noredirect=1#comment75056989_43669552) as it seems to be better for older versions of React.

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I already have these modules installed but still getting this error

Comment: @VisalGulati there's not much to go on. I suggest opening a new issue, clearly stating which versions of react, related packages and enzyme. Also include a sample test that produces the warning and the output or that test.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using React 0.14 or React <15.5, in addition to enzyme, you will have to ensure that you also have the following npm modules installed if they were not already:

```
npm i --save-dev react-addons-test-utils react-dom
```

If you are using React >=15.5, in addition to enzyme, you will have to ensure that you also have the following npm modules installed if they were not already:

```
npm i --save-dev react-test-renderer react-dom
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me

Comment: this worked for me after specifying the version of react-test-renderer to match my version of react.  Eg: `npm i --save-dev react-test-renderer@15.6.2`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update August of 2017**

If you install `react-test-renderer` it will work but all `react-*` versions should match:

e.g.
`react@15.4.2`
`react-test-renderer@15.4.2`
`react-dom@15.4.2`
`react-addons-test-utils@15.4.2`

In my environment, only this config worked!

Answer (score 1):

I was still receiving the following warning after trying steps listed above.

Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update references to remove this warning.

Updating the path in \node_modules\react-addons-test-utils\index.js solved this for me.

Old:

```
lowPriorityWarning(
  false,
  'ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. ' +
    'Update references to remove this warning.'
);

module.exports = require('react-dom/lib/ReactTestUtils');
```

New:

```
lowPriorityWarning(
  false,
  'ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. ' +
    'Update references to remove this warning.'
);

module.exports = require('react-dom/test-utils');
```