# kadira_react-layout.js Uncaught TypeError: React.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-native, react-router, meteor-accounts

I'm presently trying out Meteor and React. When I run the app it displays a blank page. I checked the console and found an error. Could that be the cause of it?

```
Layout = React.createClass({
        render(){
            return(
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <div className="box">
                        <div className="srow row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left push-down-50">
                            NavBar
                            {this.props.sidebar}
                            {this.props.content}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    });
```

console error log

```
modules.js?hash=a9c8f38…:11069Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update references to remove this warning.printWarning @ modules.js?hash=a9c8f38…:11069warning @ modules.js?hash=a9c8f38…:11093meteorInstall.node_modules.react-addons-test-utils.index.js @ modules.js?hash=a9c8f38…:31588fileEvaluate @ modules-runtime.js?hash=2b888cb…:207require @ modules-runtime.js?hash=2b888cb…:130meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.react-runtime.react-runtime.js @ react-runtime.js:38fileEvaluate @ modules-runtime.js?hash=2b888cb…:207require @ modules-runtime.js?hash=2b888cb…:130(anonymous function) @ react-runtime.js?hash=be87be9…:115(anonymous function) @ react-runtime.js?hash=be87be9…:127
kadira_react-layout.js?hash=c418396…:76 Uncaught TypeError: React.render is not a function(anonymous function) @ kadira_react-layout.js?hash=c418396…:76(anonymous function) @ kadira_react-layout.js?hash=c418396…:90
```

Comment: Not sure about the error, but the warning about `ReactTestUtils` is unrelated to your issue.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334942/reacttestutils-has-been-moved) for more details on that one.

Comment: Just posted the whole log. I understand they're 2 different concerns.

Comment: did you ever sorted this out?