# Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update references to remove this warning

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm getting this warning when including `shallow` from `enzyme`.

```
Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update references to remove this warning.
```

It seems it doesn't break the tests, it's just irritating.

I found [same issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334942/reacttestutils-has-been-moved), but solution suggested there doesn't solve it for me. Following dependencies are installed, as per my package.json

`"react": "15.4.2",
 "react-dom": "15.4.2",
 "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
 "enzyme": "^2.8.2"`

When I comment out `import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';`, I don't see this warning. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved by setting the version of `react-addons-test-utils` to `15.4.2`